# is an object casted when added to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, polymorphism

If I create an interface: `wood` that is implemented by a number of objects such as `oak` and `pine`.

When I create this:

```
Pine tree = new Pine();
Oak trunk = new Oak();

ArrayList<wood> woods = ArrayList<wood>();

woods.add(tree);
woods.add(trunk);
```

and use it thus so:

```
for(wood tree: woods){
    if(tree.gettype() == PINE)
         tree.getbranch();
    else if(tree.gettype() == OAK)
         tree.gettrunk();
}
```

does the tree object use the methods within the Oak or Pine object?

I would think, based on testing, that it would use the respective object but I just want to make sure.

Comment: woods.get(0) would return a tree object, but it would be of type wood due to the ArrayList explicit cast

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks No it wouldn't. The reference would be a Tree reference, but the object would be a Pine or an Oak. And there's no explicit cast anywhere in the displayed code.

Comment: @Kayaman Er yeah, my bad brain fart on the class names.  Also you're right, the ArrayList<wood> is an implicit cast, right?

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks I've never heard of a generics declaration being called an "implicit cast".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the tree object use the methods within the Oak or Pine object?

Yes. For instance, if `getbranch` is overridden in `Oak` or `Pine`, the version on the object being iterated, not the `wood` version, is called. So when you're looking at an `Oak`, `Oak`'s version is called; when you're looking at a `Pine`, `Pine`'s version is called. This is called [*dynamic binding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding_%28computing%29), and it's the only kind of binding Java has. (Some languages, like C++, have both dynamic and static binding depending on how you declare the method; in Java, the closest you can come is the `final` keyword, which prevents you from overriding the method at all [and therefore would allow static binding in a compiler where that was relevant, such as the optimizations that the HotSpot Just-In-Time compiler can do].)

---

Side notes:

1. The overwhelming convention in Java is that class names are capitalized. Even more important is consistency. So if you have `Oak` and `Pine` classes, their base class should be `Wood`, not `wood`.
2. Similarly, camelCase is used for methods (so, `getBranch`, not `getbranch`).

Again, this is convention, which you can choose to ignore, but when communicating with others (for instance, here on SO!), following convention is useful.

Comment: Hey, Mr. Crowder, won't there be a variable name collision as the OP has an `Oak tree` and then the variable in the for loop is also a local variable `tree` ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Yes and no. The quoted `for` loop is invalid, because the [enhanced `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) **requires** that you declare a new, loop-scoped variable. The quoted code doesn't have a type in front of it, and so won't compile. If it *did* compile, the `tree` within the loop would be the one declared in the loop, shadowing (hiding) the `tree` declared outside the loop.

Comment: I actually do not understand what the OP wants to achieve. Maybe you can help me improve my answer ? :-)

Comment: I do use the conventional naming scheme to an extent. I just wrote this on the fly and usually make sure its capitalized when creating the class so then when referenced later in code it changes to the correct case.

Comment: @LittleChild I want to ensure that I can call the class level methods when within an enhanced for loop using the interface Wood.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you cast something upwards, into their interface type, you can only use methods which are defined by that interface.

That is, you cannot use any of the more specialized methods that are defined by `Oak` and `Pine`. You can only use whatever `wood` defines.
So, if you want to use the methods that are defined by `Oak` and `Pine`, you will need to cast their objects downwards into their appropriate class types.

This:

```
for(wood tree: woods){
    if(tree.gettype() == PINE)
         tree.getbranch();
    else if(tree.gettype() == OAK)
         tree.gettrunk();
}
```

should be replaced by:

```
for(wood tree : woods){
    if(wood.getClass().getName().equals("Pine")){
        // chop that tree ! destroy nature !
    }else if(wood.getClass().getName().equals("Oak")){
        // more deforestation !
    }
}
```

Comment: lmfaooo. kudos to your forloop

Comment: btw.  I have the forloop working without using getClass() call.  So both you and T.J. Crowder's answers have given more than enough to be certain that I am getting/calling the correct methods and retrieving correct, respective data.

Comment: and back to KUDOS. just know that you received a Kudo, since I cant +2. so be proud.

Answer (score 0):

The list will only be able to contain objects that inherit `Wood`.

When you're just plainly iterating over this list, only the `Wood` methods will be available.
However any of the methods that are defined in `Wood` that are overridden in subclasses will be used (Should you create `Wood` as an abstract class with implementation for these methods, then it will fall back to that if you have a subclass that doesn't override it).

Answer (score 0):

In your case :

```
Pine tree = new Pine();
Oak trunk = new Oak();
```

you don't even need to check type to call method on object, because both object and reference are of same type. Pine or Oak.

You need to check for type if you are using RTP.

That is you create objects like `wood tree = new Pine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the distinction between the type of the reference and the type of the object.

When you say

```
Pine pine = new Pine();
ArrayList<Wood> woods = ArrayList<Wood>();
woods.add(pine);
```

there is no cast happening, and it isn't necessary. `Pine` is of type `Wood`, and this is a `List` of `Wood`s. But as you iterate over the list, remember the *references* are of type `Wood`, but the *objects* are of type `Pine`, etc. So when you call `wood.getBranch()`, you are looking at `Pine` (for example) from the `Wood` API/interface/perspective.

However, the objects themselves are `Pine`, `Oak`, and so on, so the `getBranch()` calls *for those particular objects* will be called. That's polymorphism. I can get the specific behavior for infinite kinds of objects from a broad superclass reference. So I can add more `Wood`s as my application evolves, and my code doesn't need to change.

Along those lines, keep in mind if you are doing a lot of conditional logic based on class, you are completely missing out on the benefits of an object-oriented language. Just stick to C. To understand why, imagine adding classes for `Sequoia`, `Palm`, and so on. Do you really want to add more conditionals to all the methods that have them? That's a lot of working on the weekend.